# Overwriting attr_* methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm reading this book "[The Well-Grounded Rubyist](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988657)" and this random question came to me.  I know in Ruby that it's possible to re-open a class and overwrite the method.

Example:

```
class A
  def x
    "First definition of x"
  end

  def x
    "Second definition of x"
  end
end

test = A.new
test.x #returns "Second definition of x"
```

Based on the results above, I was curious if it was possible to overwrite the class method `attr_accessor` with my own (random) definition.  Here's what I'm thinking:

```
class Dummy
  attr_accessor :test

  def self.attr_accessor(method_name)
    puts "Overwrite the default functionality of attr_accessor by printing this text instead."
  end
end

d = Dummy.new
d.test #not sure why this returns nil instead of putting my message
Dummy.attr_accessor(test) #fails because of ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2..3)
```

For the two examples above, I'm hoping to understand Ruby better by tinkering around and asking questions to get your insight.

Comment: "It's possible to re-open a method and overwrite the method"... uh... It's possible to re-open a *class* and overwrite a method.

Comment: Sorry for the terminology mix up; you're correct - what I meant to say is that it's possible to have multiple method definitions in a class.  Thanks!

Comment: That's OK. I was just checking to make sure you understood the difference. The terminology correction is important lest someone who doesn't understand the difference read it and get the wrong idea. Now, what happens if you overwrite the old definition, then code is called that uses the method, perhaps some other gem you need, and it calls `attr_accessor`, expecting it to create an instance variable's getter/setter routines, and those don't get built because of your overwrite? That's why we are very careful about overwriting core routines. Just something to think about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, and you just did it!

```
d.test #not sure why this returns nil instead of putting my message
```

returns `nil` because you used `attr_accessor :test` before redefining it below, as such, Ruby performed `attr_accessor`'s default behavior and created a member and accessors in the `Dummy` class.  It returns `nil` because the member's value is unset...`nil`.

```
Dummy.attr_accessor(test) #fails because of ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2..3)
```

fails not for the reason you think.  This call works:

```
Dummy.attr_accessor("method_name")
```

The problem is you are calling a method named `test` and not providing all of it's expected values.  See the docs for `Kernel.test()` http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-test.

The error message you are seeing is because you are calling the test method incorrectly, NOT because of a mistake in your redefinition of `attr_accessor`.

Answer (score 6):

You are on the right path, but class definitions are executed in order at runtime. You need to define your new method before calling it, otherwise the original gets used for that one.

If you do

```
class Dummy
  def self.attr_accessor(method)
    puts 'your message here'
  end
  attr_accessor :test # message printed
end

d = Dummy.new
d.test # raises an error, since we aren't creating a test method anymore
Dummy.attr_accessor(test) #will still fail, read on
```

`test` is a method in Ruby, corresponding to the `test` builtin in shells. That method is why you are getting an error at the end. What you are actually wanting is

```
Dummy.attr_accessor(:test1)
```

Note that you won't be able to call the normal `attr_accessor`, because it is a private method on the class instance that is `self` inside of the class definition. (IOW, `attr_accessor` is a private, instance method on `Module`, and when executing the class definition, `self` is an instance of `Module`)

Comment: Ah ok, so the first thing I learned is that the statement "attr_accessor :test" is actually calling the attr_accessor method I defined.

Comment: However, I noticed that running "d.test1" throughs the following error "NoMethodError: undefined method `test1'".  On the other hand, Dummy.attr_accessor(:test1) works and returns: This is the method_name: test1
 => nil.  Not sure if I really get this yet.  Any other pointers?  Thanks!

Comment: If you override `attr_accessor` without defining your own methods, or calling super (to call the original), then no method is created.

Comment: -1: `d.test` will definitely not print the message. The message will print when `attr_accessor` is called. `d.test.` will produce an error.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune nice call, not sure it was worth a downvote though

Comment: Downvotes are easily reverted, when the answer goes from wrong and misleading to correct :-)

Answer (score 2):

In your `Dummy` class the `Class` version of `attr_accessor` is called because the `Dummy` version has not been defined yet at the point when `attr_accessor` is called. If you move the definition before the call, the behaviour will be different.

```
class Dummy    
  def self.attr_accessor(method_name)
    puts "Overwrite the default functionality of attr_accessor by printing this text instead."
  end

  attr_accessor :test
end
```

This will print your message when the class definition is read. When you try to call the method `test` on a `Dummy` object, you'll get an error because no such method was defined.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you reverse the order of your `attr_accessor` call and your `def self.attr_accessor`? I don't know if that will fix it, but you certainly can't do it in your order. Remember, when you open a class with a line like `class Dummy`, you are executing real code in real time. So *first* you are calling `attr_accessor` and *then* you are trying to redefine it. Well, I don't know whether you can redefine it like that, but you certainly need to try to redefine it *before* you call it, or you'll be calling the old version!

Comment: I have in fact written a brief intro to Ruby; the fact that you didn't grasp that attr_accessor was a method call or that a def was executable code (and that these things happen in order) suggests that you might get something out of it, since it lays great stress on exactly that sort of thing: http://www.apeth.com/rubyIntro/justenoughruby.html

Comment: thanks @matt, i've started reading this and hoping to learn more from your thorough explanations!